# Display a mostly undisplayed element in a popup

Tags: css

How can I pop up the contents of a mostly undisplayed element when it is moused over?

Given

```
Some text.<span class="note">Note contents.</span> Text continues.
```

I’d like to replace the note with, say, an * (or maybe a block of color). When that is hovered over, the note contents would pop up over the underlying text (over it, not inline).

Something like:

```
.note {position: absolute; 
       display: none}
.note::before 
      {display:inline; 
       contents: "*"}
.note:hover 
      {display: inline}
```

But of course that does not work, since `.note {display:none}` also hides the ::before child.

I could do this:

```
.note {font-size: 0}   
.note::before 
      {content: "*";
       font-size: initial}
.note:hover
      {font-size: initial}
```

but that expands the note inline and I need it instead to overlay the text that continues after the note.

If I could change the HTML, I could add `<span>*</span>` before the note, and trigger the pop-up on that. But I can’t change the source HTML.

CSS3 and SASS are OK, but I can’t use Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Use `visibility`

```css
.note {
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:5px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background:#fff;
}

.note::before {
  visibility: visible;
  content: "*";
}

.note:hover {
  visibility:visible;
  width:auto;
  white-space:normal;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
Some text.<span class="note">Note contents.</span> Text continues. Something like:
```

Comment: Is there a way to make room for that *?

Comment: This is promising. Two more small issues: The underlying text jumps that 5px when I hover. Anyway to stop that? More importantly, this seems not to work if the note is too long to fit on one line.

Comment: @JPM for the *too long* you can reset the whitespace on hover .. for the jump I will try to find a way